# Loop through spreadsheet and find empty/blank cells that meet a condition

Tags: excel, vba

VBA code should loop through spreadsheet and highlight the cells within a range that meet a condition. For example: for each employee row at least 1 of 7 columns must have a value. The required columns/range are separated. Starting at column U, W, Z, AB, AG, AJ etc. within my VBA code each column is set as a select case, and upon clicking a button to validate it loops through. I have tried rngoffset and calling from a function and I'm still stuck. The only way is to call under each Case. Is there a better way? If needed I can provide some sample code.

Thanks

Sample code:

```
Case Band2Bonus:
```

‘If column is not hidden, then perform validation
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
If ws.Column(intcol).Hidden=False Then
‘clear array

```
Set quickArray= Nothing
Set rngOffset1= Nothing
Set rngOffset2= Nothing
Set rngOffset3= Nothing
Set rngOffset4= Nothing
Set rngOffset5= Nothing
Set rngOffset6= Nothing
Set rngOffset7= Nothing
str=””
```

‘Quick-fill array using variant

```
quickArray= ws.Cells(lngHeader+1,intCol).Resize(lngLastRow)
For lngRow=lngHeader + 1 To lngLastRow

Set rngOffset1= ws.Cells(lngRow Band2Bonus)
Set rngOffset2= ws.Cells(lngRow Band3Bonus)
Set rngOffset3= ws.Cells(lngRow Band4Bonus)
Set rngOffset4= ws.Cells(lngRow Step1Band)
Set rngOffset5= ws.Cells(lngRow Step2Band)
Set rngOffset6= ws.Cells(lngRow Step3Band)
Set rngOffset7= ws.Cells(lngRow Step4Band)

If CBool ((rngOffset1.Value = “” And rngOffset2.Value = “” And _ 
           rngOffset3.Value = “” And rngOffset4.Value = “” And _ 
           rngOffset5.Value = “” And rngOffset6.Value = “” And _
           rngOffset7.Value = “”)) Or _
Not ValidBand(quickArray((lngRow-lngHeader), 1)) Then 
   lngErrorCount=lngErrorCount +1
    ws.Cells(lngRow,intcol).Interior.colorIndex=failedvalidation
Else 
ws.Cells(lngRow,intcol).Value= UCase(ws.Cells(lngRow,intCol).Value)

End If
   Next lngRow
End If
```

Case SetPlan:
‘conditional field based off of set up menu selection- only added to view order of sheet

Case Band3Bonus:
‘If column is not hidden, then perform validation
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
If ws.Column(intcol).Hidden=False Then
‘clear array
Set quickArray= Nothing
Set rngOffset1= Nothing

'etc.... code will continue run through each case. I was just hoping there was a better way to run through this range

Comment: Please include your attempt at creating this code in your question, and then explain where you ran into trouble. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a place to go to when you have an idea and want someone else to write all the code for you. If you cannot "find a code" that does what you want, then you will need to create it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you just highlight with conditional formatting?

Comment: braX- Per my original question. I stated that if needed I could provide sample code.